# Unable to build dotnet project in docker

Tags: .net, docker

I'm new to docker and i was trying to migrate my API written in .NET 6 from IIS to a Docker.

So i've wrote a Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# copy all the layers' csproj files into respective folders
COPY ./VisualOrder.csproj src/

# run restore over API project - this pulls restore over the dependent projects as well
RUN dotnet restore "src/VisualOrder.csproj"

COPY . .

# run build over the API project
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build

# run publish over the API project
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN ls -l
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "VisualOrder.dll" ]
```

But the issue is that at `RUN dotnet build ...` the build fails with the following error:

> Restored /src/VisualOrder.csproj (in 338 ms).
> #15 1.897 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(356,5):
> error NETSDK1073: The FrameworkReference
> 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App' was not recognized
> [/src/VisualOrder.csproj]

I tried to run dotnet restore on my PC by deleting bin and obj folders but on my PC all works as it have to.

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
    <UserSecretsId>d96c762d-ae98-4b1d-a27d-af48bb400d26</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Emails\EmailNegozio.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Emails\EmailRiepilogo.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Emails\EmailNegozio.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Emails\EmailRiepilogo.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="bundleconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.27" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="PayPalCheckoutSdk" Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="PayPalHttp" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="QRCoder" Version="1.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorEngine.NetCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="39.80.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Are you expecting to run a desktop application with a GUI inside a container?

Comment: can you add this file `src/VisualOrder.csproj`?

Comment: @DanielMann i just would set up my APis service on container which then will communicate with another container with Angular (front-end) service

Comment: @NoamYizraeli just added the file

Comment: `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>` should be `net6.0`

Comment: @LeiYang i solved it by setting output type to class library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the following issue by setting in project properties > output type > class library

by default VisualStudio sets it to 'Console application'.

[image]